# How do i dynamically import a function in nextjs typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using a react modal library called react-st-modal, and I'm trying to import a hook called useDialog. My code doesnt work and looks like this:

```
const Dialog = dynamic<Function>(
  import("react-st-modal").then(module => module.useDialog) as any)
```

`Dialog` is a type, and cannot be used as a function. what can i do

Comment: Why are you trying to import a hook dynamically? Is the goal to import the full dialog component dynamically too?

Answer (score -1):

`import` function is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`. Just use `Promise` generic type like `Promise<type>`.

Your var will be function that return `Promise`.

Comment: the var will not be a function, as dynamic returns a component

Comment: @user14850280 It's a Promise that return some value, you can set any like you did it above

Comment: This is not correct dynamic has this signature... `export default function dynamic<P = {}>(dynamicOptions: DynamicOptions<P> | Loader<P>, options?: DynamicOptions<P>): React.ComponentType<P>;`